# Python 3 : Inheritance and the assignment of "self"

Tags: python, inheritance, typeerror

Why does this script require "self" as an argument to mssg() in line 3? PyCharm flags "self" in line 3 as, expected type "Another", got "Main" instead.  This warning makes sense to me (although the code works).  When "self" is omitted, Python throws an error:

TypeError: mssg() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

```
class Main():
    def __init__(self):

        print(Another.mssg(self))

class Another():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def mssg(self):
        return "Hello World"

_foo = Main()
```

Using your guidance, here are three different ways to prevent the TypeError:

```
class Main():
    def __init__(self):

        print(Another.mssg('asdasdsa'))
        print(Another().mssg())
        print(_bar.mssg())

class Another():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def mssg(self):
        return "Hello World"
_bar = Another()
_foo = Main()
```

Comment: Because only access through an instance binds the instance as the first argument, otherwise, `Another.mssg` is just the function you wrote right there which requires exactly one positional argument

Comment: Recommend: https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified

Comment: But... even if I create an instance of _bar = Another(), just before _foo, I still get the same TypeError.  Where should the instance be created?

Comment: "But... even if I create an instance of _bar = Another(), just before _foo, I still get the same TypeError." It has nothing to do with that. You'll **always** get an error if you try to do `Another.mssg()` with no arguments. You either have to pass an argument to it (in this case, nothing is done with the value so it could literally be anything, which sort of tells you this shouldn't be amethod to start with), **or** create an instance of `another = Another()` and call the method on the instance, `another.mssg()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use `Another.mssg(self)`, then your are calling a **class method**, that is why `self` is taken as a parameter and you need to use exactly one argument to call the function. Try `print(Another.mssg('asdasdsa'))` and you will see that it works.

If your intention was using `mssg(self)` as an **instance method**, then you should call it using `print(Another().mssg())`, so you create your instance and then you call its method.

Comment: "If you use Another.mssg(self), then your are calling a class method, " No, you aren't. Note, `Another.mssg(self)` *works already*

Comment: `Another.mssg(self)` is clearly not an instance method, so I think it is a static method or a class method. As you don't use an argument, you can use whatever you want, that is why `''asdasdsa"`, `""` or `self` could work.